# Converting Table into an Accordion via BOOTSTRAP

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I need to convert an existing table that pulls information from a database into an Accordion layout

I have not been able to get anything to work properly

The main page I am trying to convert is  "https://www.collectorwiz.com/weblinks.php" ... I would like for each "weblink group" to be a dropdown so when clicked.. all "weblink" names & links will open and close as an accordion -

I can provide the code that needs BOOTSTRAP conversion to an accordion layout (if you can help me) Thank You

this is the page  "https://www.collectorwiz.com/weblinks_content.php"

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: My programmer recently passed away and I don't know a thing about bootstrap... but I am willing to learn.... He had coded my site with private coding... not wordpress... and I am just trying to simplify things....

Comment: Sorry to hear about your programmer, but we need code and be clear on what is the issue and what results you want. First of put code that is causing the issue in question.